How to avoid manually passing props up the hierarchy in Svelte components
I have a Svelte component that accepts a prop for handling input changes, structured as follows:
<!-- A.svelte -->
<script>
    export let onChange = (value) => {};
</script>

<input
    type="number"
    bind:value
    on:change={() => onChange(value || '')}
/>

Then, I have another component that uses this component:
<!-- B.svelte -->
<script>
    export let onChange = () => {};
</script>

<p>Enter your age</p>
<A
    onChange={onChange}
/>

Notice how I have to pass onChange manually up the hierarchy in addition to having to define it. Is there a way to avoid that?

Side note: In Svelte 5, the recommended solution is to pass along listeners/callbacks this very same way as you are doing now. It makes the code explicit and easy to read and understand.


Regular element events (and those sent via the Svelte dispatcher) would not need to be declared as prop and can be forwarded using only on:change (no handler, just the name).
(Bubbling) DOM events (dispatched directly to an element) travel up the DOM hierarchy and can be handled at any point in the tree. May need to wrap a component in an element so you can attach the handler there.
There are also contexts that can be used for communication, though they need to be set higher up and create somewhat of a coupling between components.
One can also (ab)use the window as an event bus, i.e. dispatch to that and handle anywhere using <svelte:window on:my-event={...} />

